# Channel of type "set"

Tags: go, channel

I recently started writing Go after years of programming in C#, and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around several concepts of the language. Here's an example of what I'm trying to solve: I'd like to be able to create  a routine that iterates over a list, calls a function, and stores the output in a buffered channel. The issue is I want to return a **distinct** set of these output values, as the function can return similar results for two different elements in the list.

Since Go doesn't have a built-in set type, I'm trying to use a `map[string]bool` to store distinct values (using `map[string]bool` or `map[string]struct` is what others suggested as a replacement for a set); and I'm using a buffered channel to insert into this map, however I'm not certain what the right syntax for inserting 1 element into a map would look like. Here's  what I'm trying to do:

```
resultsChnl := make(chan map[string]bool, len(myList))
go func(myList []string, resultsChnl chan map[string]bool) {
    for _, item := range myList {

        result, err := getResult(item)
        /* error checking */

        resultsChnl <- {result: true}
    }

    close(resultsChnl)
}(myList, resultsChnl)

for item := range resultsChnl {
    ...
}
```

Obviously this doesn't compile due to invalid syntax of `resultsChnl <- {result: true}`. I know this sounds impractical since naturally in this particular case I could create a local map inside the for loop and assign one `map[string]bool` object to a non-buffered channel and return that, but let's assume I was creating a go routine for each item in the list and really wanted to use a buffered channel (as opposed to using a mutex to grab a lock on a shared map). So is there any way to insert one key-value pair in a map channel? Or am I thinking about this completely wrong?

Comment: Maps with a single entry are pointless if the value is just a sentinel. However, judging from the question you'll want to turn a slice into a set (i.e. map[string]bool) and *then* send the map into the channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question directly, you would want

```
resultsChnl <- map[string]bool{result: true}
```

But this doesn't seem useful at all. You may want to *collect* the results in a map, but there's no reason to pass a map over the channel for each result when you know it will only have one element. Simply use a channel of `string`, do

```
resultsChnl <- result
```

for each result in your producer goroutine, and

```
seenResult[item] = true
```

in your consumer loop to collect the results (where `seenResult` is a `map[string]bool`).

Or forget about the channel entirely and have your producer goroutines write directly into a [sync.Map](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map).

Comment: Ah. The syntax makes sense. Yep as I mentioned in the question I know this is impractical I was mostly just curious about the syntax. And now that I have seen the syntax I totally see why I was on the wrong track :) Thanks!

Comment: Oooh `sync.Map`. Interesting.

Comment: To add to this, there's no concept of `Map.Entry<K, V>` in go. If you want to keep pairs of elements together then you would need to create your own struct type to hold them, and pass that.

Comment: Thanks @Zak. That makes sense.